# subtracting bn values with a and store in c using php

Tags: php

plz help me out to solve this below code works fine but wt i need is there is another var named as rollno the $b array is separated according to rollno for eg:500, 2000, 1500 belongs to roll no:1 and 750, 800 belongs to roll no:2 according to this the below process should done

```
$a = 230500;    
$b = array(500, 2000, 1500, 1000, 750, 800, 900, 1300, 2000, 2500, 1400, 8000); //up to n number
foreach($b as $key){        
 $a = $a - $key;   
 $c = $a;     
 echo $c.'<br>';   
}
```

i above code it takes all $b as key and sub with a it should need to separate $b according to rollno..

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is you want.

```
$a = 230500;    
$b = array(500, 2000, 1500, 1000, 750, 800, 900, 1300, 2000, 2500, 1400, 8000); // up to n number
foreach($b as $key => $val){        
    $a = $a - $val;                
}
$c = $a;    
echo $c;
```

Comment: hi almost like this but i had edited as above plz check it..